# Betweenness and Centrality in QGIS

Tags: qgis, network-analysis

I would like to analyze my network for Betweenness and Centrality.

In a paper u read:

- Betweenness score measures the number of times the link (street segment) lies on the shortest paths between other pairs of street segments. In other words, it measures the number of paths that pass a street segment.
- Centrality score measures the difficulty (on average) of navigating to all
  possible destinations (links street segments) from each link (street segment).

Network design was evaluated via betweenness and centrality scores for each street segment using
“Spatial Design Network Analysis” extension for ArcGIS. This is the result.

[image]

I have tried with `v.net.centrality`, but instead of nicely colored links, I got nodes and that is not what I would like to have.

Do you have any idea how to do it in QGIS?

This is the paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877042814056869

Comment: Try the following workflow: (1) `v.net.centrality` (2) convert nodes to isolines (3) colour them the way you prefer via Symbology

Comment: I will try. Ant let you know when I get the results tomorrow. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @ Taras I did something different - `Join attributes by location (summary)`. From the vertices layer I have chosen betweenness and then calculated the sum, mean etc. for betweenness since every segment touches two vertices.